# Split a Map into sublists

Tags: java, linked-list, hash-map

I may get a `Map` of many many items that needs to be requested to an API.

In order to improve performance, I thought about splitting that list into smaller sublists, and querying the API with this small subset.

For that, I came to this code and was wondering what was your opinion on it.

This is some banal initiator I used to test my code:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 550;i ++) {
    map.put(String.valueOf(i), i);
}
```

Now the real code:

```
    int length = 100;
    List<Integer> items = new LinkedList<Integer>(map.values());
    int pages = (int) Math.ceil((double) items.size() / length);

    for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        List<Integer> sub = items.subList(i * length, ((i+1) * length > items.size() ? items.size() : (i+1) * length));
        System.out.println(sub.get(0));
        System.out.println(sub.get(sub.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("--");

        // In my case, I would call the API here, at that place, using the sublist
    }
```

The final output is:

> ```
> 0
> 99
> --
> 100
> 199
> --
> 200
> 299
> --
> 300
> 399
> --
> 400
> 499
> --
> 500
> 549
> --
> ```

This works great. What's your opinion on it?

Comment: Can you describe the problem domain and what the code does a little better? This question was flagged as Unclear and I tend to agree with that assessment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is simple enough to require any comments. Just a few things:

- Is LinkedList a requirement? Can't it be done by an ArrayList?
- Use Math.min while making the subList.

An alternative for simpler solution
You can add the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library to your project and use the [Lists.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) method, e.g.

```
List<Integer> items = ...
List<List<Integer>> subLists= Lists.partition(items, pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a better alternative from the StackOverflow website :

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T[]> chunks(ArrayList<T> bigList,int n){
    ArrayList<T[]> chunks = new ArrayList<T[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i += n) {
        T[] chunk = (T[])bigList.subList(i, Math.min(bigList.size(), i + n)).toArray();         
        chunks.add(chunk);
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233731/330867)

I believe it's better because :

- There is less code
- Less calculs (ceil)
- Less looping size (not from 1 to `size()`, but up to `size()` by `length` jumps)